# Xamarin.Android Retrieve Facebook Profile Error

Tags: c#, android, facebook, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get user information from facebook using this code:

```
                    auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                    {
                        if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            OAuthConfig.User = new UserDetails();
                            // Get and Save User Details 
                            OAuthConfig.User.Token = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"];//oauth_token"];
                            OAuthConfig.User.ExpiresIn = eventArgs.Account.Properties["expires_in"];

                            var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,gender"), null, eventArgs.Account);
                            var response = request.GetResponseAsync();
                            var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

                            var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var name = obj["first_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var lastName = obj["last_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var email = obj["email"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                            //var user = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(id, accessToken, expiryDate);

                            OAuthConfig.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // The user cancelled
                        }
                    };
```

However, i get this error on line ( `var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());` ) :

```
'Task<Response>' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponseText' ...
```

What reference am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use await to get result and not the task

```
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

You will need to define the follow

```
auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
```